# Any way to print contents of a screen to a web page?

Tags: php, linux, sh

I'm running a minecraft server on a screen (screen -X mc java -jar minecraft_server.jar).  Is there any way to print the contents of this onto a web page?  I was thinking it would be something along the lines of

```
<?php
$console = exec(console.sh)
echo $console;
header("refresh: 5";);
?>
```

however this does not print anything.  I think it has something to do with the screens being per-user, is there any way to let php run this?  Or is there anyway to output the screen to a file and still be able to attach to the screen?

Thanks a ton!

Edit:
Answer below works well, however I would suggest http://phpshell.sourceforge.net.  You can log into the terminal and display the console along with being able to chat.  However this is interactive, and would work only for admins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of these should work.

```
<?php
$logs = "PATH_TO_SERVER_LOGS/server.log";
$fh = fopen($logs, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($logs));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
header("refresh: 5");
?>

<?php
//Replace ./server.log with the path to your server logs and make sure apache has the proper //permissions to read the file.
$file = file_get_contents('./server.log', true);
echo $file;
header("refresh: 5");
?>
```

Comment: Only one problem, it doesn't print new lines.  I don't know if there is a way to fix this or not.

Comment: Replace echo $theData; with echo nl2br($theData); or if you used the second method, replace echo $file with echo nl2br($file);